# error: failed to push some refs to gitlab repo

Tags: git

I would like to solve a problem I am having *and* learn the correct way of doing things.

**My situation**

I pull code from a gitlab repository. I created a feature branch, and edited one source file and then committed it. Then I pushed it with `git push origin FeatureBranch`. As a result of this I got a merge request.

However I left it for a couple of days.

Turns out that other people have modified the code and merged it into the master branch so *The source branch is 7 commits behind the target branch*

So, I do this

```
git fetch origin master
git checkout master
git tag last_master2
git merge origin/master
git checkout FeatureBranch
git rebase master
git push origin FeatureBranch
```

and I got the error

```
To https:<gitlab repo>
 ! [rejected]        FeatureBranch -> FeatureBranch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to <gitlab repo>
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So my questions are:

- What did I do wrong?
- How do I do this right?

Comment: In this particular case, since you have rebased successfully, you probably want the `git push --force-with-lease` option.